# Solr Query for Range of UUID

Tags: solr

I'm trying to write a query that returns all the documents within a range of UUIDs.  I expect there to be 3 docs in the result, but there are may more.  It seems like my range query is not working.

Here is my range query:

```
&fq=id:"25e12906-ee0d-45d5-b53c-de4b3f4e54de" TO "ac416be1-4d2e-45f9-bcb8-39b514a2659d"
```

When I do not include this filter, `25e12906-ee0d-45d5-b53c-de4b3f4e54de` is the first item returned, and `ac416be1-4d2e-45f9-bcb8-39b514a2659d` is the 3rd.  Thats why I am expecting 3 in my result.  My result however has much more (44 items).

Is what I am doing possible?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a range query, you need to use [the proper syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser):

```
fq=id:[25e12906-ee0d-45d5-b53c-de4b3f4e54de TO ac416be1-4d2e-45f9-bcb8-39b514a2659d]
```

And of course you have make sure you have tokenized those ids the right way (not spliting on the dash etc)